# Skip certain step in index based loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```js
for (i=1; i<101; i=i+1){
    console.log(i)
}
```

I made this loop to count from 1 to 100 and what I need is to change the added value from  i++ to i=i+5 every 10  numbers.

Example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (skip) 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 (skip) 29...
```

Comment: I'd recommend you check out the basics of programming.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a check and increment with an additional `5` if the value goes over a certain limit.

Basically you want this result

> ```
>   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
>  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37
>  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51
>  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65
>  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
>  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93
>  99 100
> ```

and what you see at the end of the first line, the value of 9 is a fixed value and every next value in a column is a value which adds 14 to the value a line above.

You need to eleminate the start value to get a normalized value without offset by subtracting of `9` and you need to check the modulo with 14 and add only then the value of `5` if the modulo is zero.

That means only with the values like `9`, `23`, `37`, `52`, ..., you need to add the value of `5`.

```js
var result = [],
    i;

for (i = 1; i < 101; i += 1 + 5 * !((i - 9) % 14)) {
    result.push(i);
}

console.log(result.join(' '));
```

Comment: I need someone to explain whats happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to skip `5` steps after every `9`,

```js
var maxValue = 101;
var stepsToSkip = 5;
var stepsToSkipAfter = 9;
for (var i = 1; i < maxValue; i = i + stepsToSkipAfter) 
{
   for( var j = i; j < i + stepsToSkipAfter && j < maxValue; j++ )
   {
       console.log(j);
   }   
   i = i + stepsToSkip;
}
```

**Note**

- SO's console output may not show all the values, so check the developer tools' console of your browser.

Comment: That's not what Op wants. He want to skip steps every 10 steps, not when the index is a multiple of ten. I.e. when i is 10, 24, 38...

Comment: @MalteHartwig yeah, i overlooked that part and have fixed it now. Looks like OP's requirement wasn't that trivial :)

Answer (score 1):

Increment value based on condition.

```js
var res = [];

// use variable `j` for counting and
// calculate increment value based on that

// on every 10th element you need to skip next 5 elements
// so use j for counting and based on the remainder 
// increment with 6 or 1 and while skipping increment the counter as well
for (var i = 1, j = 1; i < 101; j++, i += j % 10 ? 1 : (j++, 6)) {
  res.push(i)
}

console.log(res.join(', '));
```

Comment: That's not what Op wants. He want to skip steps every 10 steps, not when the index is a multiple of ten. I.e. when i is 10, 24, 38...

Answer (score 1):

Doing a bit of math and looking at your sequence, it becomes clear that we need to skip when `i = 14n+10`. You can put this in the step part of the for loop:

```
for (i = 1; i < 101; i = i + ((i + 5) % 14 == 0 ? 6 : 1)){
    console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var j = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (j === 9) {
    j = 0;
    i += 5;
  } else {
    console.log(i);
    j++;
  }
}
```